# How to parse an uploaded txt file in Rails3

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form which have a file input;

```
<%form_tag '/dboss/newsbsresult' , :remote=>true do %>
    <input type="file" id="examsendbutton" name="txtsbs"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Gonder">
<%end%>
```

Here i want the user to select a txt file which i try to parse and use at server, but i cannot catch the uploaded file with this code,

```
def newsbsresult
        @u = params[:txtsbs] #Or params[:txtsbs].to_s
        p @u
end
```

What is the true way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX requests do not support file uploads out of the box -- or technically, at all. This is because JavaScript can't read the data from the file field directly (except in HTML 5). There are a number of ways to do AJAX-like file uploads (e.g. [file-uploader](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader) or [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/), amongst older techniques), but Rails does not support these by simply setting `:remote => true` - you have to use something else/additional to get it to work.

The easy solution is to **remove** `:remote => true` and **add** `:multipart => true`.

---

Further reading:

- http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2010/7/30/html5-powered-ajax-file-uploads
- https://github.com/davesouth/mongoid-carrierwave-uploadify

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `:multipart => true` to your `form_tag`

```
<% form_tag '/dboss/newsbsresult' , :remote=>true, :multipart => true do %>
```

Comment: Multipart is the http header to enable file uploading

Comment: `multipart/form-data` is a different encoding of the form data that allows file uploads. This is important since files have extra meta-data, like content type, filename, etc. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, if my understand is right. you want to read data from the upload file.
I was ran in similar thing that need to show uploaded text in the another text area on my Rails application.

Here is what i did.

### View

```
  1 <%= form_tag('/dboss/newsbsresult' , :multipart => true) do %>  
  2   <input type="file" id="examsendbutton" name="txtsbs"/><br/>
  3   <input type="submit" value="Gonder">
  4 <% end %>
```

### Controller

```
  1   def index
  2     if (params[:txtsbs].present?)
  3       @upload_text = params[:txtsbs].read
  4       render :text => @upload_text
  5    end
  6   end
```

### Route

```
  match 'dboss/newsbsresult' => 'user#index'
```